# Apache not returning ErrorDocument on upstream 500

Tags: apache

We want apache to return a custom page or message when our upstream service returns 500. To this end we configured and endpoint `/500` upstream which always returns 500 and the message "boo" and told apache to return "sorry" on 500 errors:

```
ErrorDocument 500 "sorry"
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteRule "/here/500" "http://upstream/500" [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

When we call `http://frontend/here/500` however, apache just sends this `500 "boo"` response through - according to the config it should return the body `"sorry"`:

Comment: Try adding `ProxyErrorOverride On` to your VirtualHost configuration

Comment: Yep, that solved it - feel free to post it as the answer. Thanks @DusanBajic !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to override error pages for proxied content, you need to explicitly enable it in your configuration (default value is `Off`)

```
ProxyErrorOverride On
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride

Comment: Unfortunately `ProxyErrorOverride On` catches all upstream errors not just the ones we specify (even 400) and replaces them with a generic apache message which is not what we want.

Comment: Indeed so, I don't know of a way to make it selective, it is either all or nothing