# Apache & NodeJS Express = how use same 404 page

Tags: node.js, apache, express, proxypass

I'm using proxy on Apache to **proxypass subfolder of domain** to Node.js Express app on local port, but is there a way from Express side, somehow to pass purely a status in a way, so Apache uses own error page? (I want them to look the same).

As far as I know I may either use absolute path on server to that page etc, but that may not be consistent if I change the Apache settings. Is there any way to tell Apache over proxy request response, to show his error page, whatever it has been set to?

Maybe there is no such way, I just wonder if there is some way. The best I came up so far is to redirect to same URL but starting with **/e/** which would work, but remains /e/ in URL - not bad, but maybe someone give a better hint.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63617709/1145196

Comment: @DusanBajic thank you, looks like what i wanted, somehow i missed that, sure it s part ox proxy directives. Thank you.